# Insert Row borders in Excel from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a macro when outlook opens to insert some data from an email, into a row in excel, I want to add a border to the range in my excel row A to AE.

I am using `intRow4` to determine the row address where my information is being entered. 
so my code looks like this, but I am getting an object undefined error on `Dim Rng As Range` because I get the feeling outlook doesn't support it.

```
Const SHEET_NAME4 = "Statistics"
excWks4 As Object, _
intRow4 As Integer, _
Set excWks4 = excWkb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME4)
intRow4 = excWks4.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1



Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = ws2.Range("A" & intRow4 & ":AE" & intRow4 & "")

    With Rng.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
```

can someone please show me where I am going wrong with this? Thank you

Comment: Also do not use `intRow4 = excWks4.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1` You might get unexpected results and end up creating borders where not required. Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) method to find the last row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlContinuous`, `vbBlack` and `xlThin` are Excel constants. Outlook will not recognize them if you are using late binding. Add this to the top of your code.

```
Const xlContinuous As Integer = 1
Const vbBlack As Integer = 0
Const xlThin As Integer = 2
```

Also if you are using Last Binding then change `Dim Rng As Range` to `Dim Rng As Object`